# What are the legal implications of evicting a foreign host child?

Tags: united-states, child-abuse

So, I know of a family in the US that (years ago) agreed to host a teenager from a foreign country, but later tried to kick them out without a flight home. (Thankfully the situation worked out... not great... But it worked out).

The police never became involved, but if they had what could have happened? I can't imagine this being legal, but I can't find any similar situations.  It was not the family's child, and the teen was not a U.S. citizen (but she did have a foreign family that cared about her).

Answer (score 4):

The police only get involved with criminal matters. So when your question assumes police involvement, the logical conclusion is the host parents allegedly committed some crime.

If that were the case, let's say the crime were something like child abuse, criminal negligence or abandonment of a minor. Then the prosecutor's office and/or CPS (Child Protective Services) would do an investigation and, if warranted, refer the matter to the jurisdictional prosecuting attorney's office who could file criminal charges and pursue a prosecution.

Comment: The question does say "evicting" so I would have to assume it is the guest i.e. child who has does some wrong, not the hosts.